# Output list of all Active Directory users and all groups each user is a member of

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to query Active Directory to get a list of all users and all groups each user is a member of. I only need the direct groups each user is a member of, not the nested groups. The end-goal is to output this list to a CSV file. I'm attempting to do this using PowerShell in Windows Server 2012 R2.

**UPDATE**

So I've now managed to output a list of all users' names, however only some of the users's groups are included in the output, using the following command:

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=user)" -property "memberOf" | 
select -Property @{n='name';e={$_.name}},@{n='groups';e
{$($_.MemberOf | Get-adgroup | % {$_.name}) -join ','}}
```

I'm unable to determine why only *some* of the users output (probably only 5-10 total) include the groups the user is a member of, while the rest (95%) of the users output only display the name of the user, without any groups at all.

Any ideas from here?

Comment: There is a curly bracket missing, but it's before the last pipe. Should be: `... | select -exp name}} | where {$_.groups}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late reply to this post, but I built a script that output all Groups in a specific OU and all users of each group. Only downside is that the "owner" of each group is also a member, so there is a bit of redundancy, but nothing breaking for my purpose. The output is formatted into two columns.

```
$mGroups=@(
Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=,OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=" | select name);


$col = @()
for ($i=0
 $i -lt $mGroups.Count;
 $i++)
 {
      $agents=@(
      Get-ADGroupMember $mGroups[$i].name | select sAMAccountName)

        for ($n=0
             $n -lt $agents.Count;
             $n++)
             {
              $agentList = [PSCustomObject]@{
              Group = $mGroups[$i].name 
              Agents = $agents[$n].sAMAccountName
             }
            $col+=$agentList;
             }
   }          
$col
$col | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation C:\Path\to\file.type
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'am afraid that `Get-ADuser -Filter {group -eq 'Domain Users'}` just give nothing.

You can try to begin :

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=user)" -property "memberof" | select -Property @{n='name';e={$_.SamAccountName}},@{n='groups';e={$_.MemberOf -join ','}}
```

Then you can modify the filter to also take InetOrgPerson.

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))" -property "memberof" | select -Property @{n='name';e={$_.SamAccountName}},@{n='groups';e={$_.MemberOf -join ','}}
```

Then you can take the samAccountName of the group DN

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPFilter "(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))" -property "memberof" | select -Property @{n='name';e={$_.SamAccountName}},@{n='groups';e={$($_.MemberOf | Get-adgroup | % {$_.SamAccountname}) -join ','}}
```

Comment: It should be `"group -eq 'Domain Users'"` instead of `{group -eq 'Domain Users'}`. It never ceases to amaze me how anyone at Microsoft could consider it a good idea to put scriptblock notation in the examples of the `Get-ADUser` documentation when the parameter definition clearly says `<string>`.

Comment: That's why I'am using LDAPFilter, I prefer the real LDAP filter syntax.

Comment: ditto that on LDAPFilter syntax. Whoever thought changing so many property names on the ADUser object from what they are in the underlying LDAP object was a good idea needs to take a long hard look at themselves in the mirror.

Comment: Thanks so much for the post! The query worked, however the output isn't exactly what I was looking for. It seemed to output all the SamAccountname values, but only certain ones were also output with the corresponding group memberships. Beyond that, is there a way to export the output into a CSV file? Is it as simple as `Export-CSV 'Path-to-csv'`?

Comment: You should verify yourself, but memberof is the right property, the difference may come from security group versus non security group (the query can be adjusted this way). For the CSV, you can pipe the result into it.